# How to support HTTP headers NetworkImage in flutter web

Tags: flutter, http-headers, flutter-web

I tried to get some images from the internet in flutter web that need to add headers.
I've used cached_network_image: ^2.5.1 and it doesn't support the web completely also Image.network seems when running flutter on the web, headers are not used. Both of these ways successfully work on the Android release.
[image]

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With **cached_network_image: 3.0.0** I got it working to add headers by using the CachedNetworkImageProvider class.

```dart
CachedNetworkImageProvider(
              "${IOConfig.apiUrl}",
              headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer $apiToken",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept"}                                                
             ,imageRenderMethodForWeb: ImageRenderMethodForWeb.HttpGet)
```

I had to start it with an argument to change the web-renderer

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

Comment: This is it!. but I use **CachedNetworkImage** with _imageRenderMethodForWeb_.
It needs      
`import package:cached_network_image_platform_interface/cached_network_image_platform_interface.dart`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this particular limitation is due to the reduced customization capabilities of the `img` HTML-element itself. Fortunately, there are many other ways to display network images - here are just two examples:

Using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package:

```dart
  void loadImageV1(String url, Map<String, String>? headers) async {
    final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers);
    final blob = html.Blob([res.bodyBytes]);
    setState(() {
      _url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    });
  }
```

or using exposed by browser [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```dart
  void loadImageV2(String url, Map<String, String>? headers) async {
    final res = await html.window.fetch(url, {'method': 'GET', 'headers': headers});
    final blob = await res.blob();
    setState(() {
      _url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    });
  }
```

And now we can use generated syntetic url with *Image.Network* constructor.

Here is full demo:

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(DemoApp());

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Network Image Demo',
      home: NextLabPage(),
    );
  }
}

const imgUrl = 'https://robohash.org/1234';
const imgHeaders = {'Accept': 'image/*', 'Accept-language': 'en'};

class NextLabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NextLabPageState createState() => _NextLabPageState();
}

class _NextLabPageState extends State<NextLabPage> {
  String? _url;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadImageV1(imgUrl, imgHeaders);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_url != null) html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(_url!);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void loadImageV1(String url, Map<String, String>? headers) async {
    final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers);
    final blob = html.Blob([res.bodyBytes]);
    setState(() {
      _url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    });
  }

  void loadImageV2(String url, Map<String, String>? headers) async {
    final res = await html.window.fetch(url, {'method': 'GET', 'headers': headers});
    final blob = await res.blob();
    setState(() {
      _url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: _url != null ? Image.network(_url!) : Text('Loading...'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why even convert to a blob? I would just pass the bytes to a memory image, so it's not web exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the image to a blob, I recommend just passing the raw bytes to a memory image:

```
  Uint8List? _imageBytes;

  void loadImage(String url, Map<String, String>? headers) async {
    final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: headers);
    setState(() {
      _imageBytes = res.bodyBytes;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: _imageBytes == null ? Text('Loading...') : Image.memory(_imageBytes!),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Remember to use the `errorBuilder` parameter of `Image`, in case the request has failed or doesn't contain a valid image.